# Sharing session from tomcat application to websphere application

Tags: session, spring-boot, tomcat8, websphere-7, httpsession

I am trying to share the session from tomcat application (written in spring boot) to a different application deployed on websphere application server . In WAS the session is coming as null.
ResponseSessionId is not getting set.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Never heard this was an option... how could you do that with different JVMs? and even different products?. There is no Java EE standard about session standarization.

You can share info within WAS if WARs are in the same EAR.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/hazem/entry/sharing_session_between_multiple_wars_in_the_same_ear_for_websphere_applications1?lang=en

But I don't think you can do much more than that.